# Cannot paste files into System/Media

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, root-access, file-permissions, copy-paste, droid-explorer

I am looking to change my boot audio but cannot change it due it not copying from my computer to my phone but I can copy from the device to my computer.

I have the latest version of Android Studio / SDK
I have the latest version of Droid Explorer

I can view my files and copy from but can't paste to my device.

Please can someone help

---

Hello my device is rooted and has supersu and exposed framework and BusyBox

---

Also I can make those changes if I copy to sd card and use es file explorer to paste them to system media folder.  Also before I installed busybox the folder contents of my device didn't display in Droid explorer it would connect but was a blank directory so that's been fixed but as for file permissions it hasn't as I have rooted it and given ADB root permissions etc but can only take files from the device in Droid explorer but can't paste them to the device

Comment: `/system` is read-only, so you cannot write there. I further assume your device is not rooted?

Comment: Agree with @Izzy for further guessing non-rooted. A rooted phone user is not asking such a trivial question here.

Comment: What do you need in that directory? Ringtones, alarms, etc. Can be placed in multiple locations and will work properly. What is the end result you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @acejavelin Change **boot** audio without modifying `/system`?

Answer (score -1):

You need to root the device and give permission to copy files using any root explorer.